# Getting Error when Creating the Database Migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a database migration with the command :

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial
```

but every time I'm getting this error :
[image]

Unfortunately, I can't progress anymore because of this error, what the is the problem here?
that's how I configurated the connection string :

first in appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Data": {
        "SportStoreProducts": {
            "ConnectionStrings":"Server(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=SportsStore;Trusted _Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" 
        } 
    }
}
```

and then in the Startup:

```
 public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:SportStoreProducts:ConnectionString"]));
```

I'm not sure about the version of EF, that's how I added the package in SportStore.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" 
Version="2.0.3" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" 
Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
```

from this folder, I run the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Mohsen\Google Drive\ASP.MVC Projects\SportsStore\SportsStore
```

and my DbContext class is called:

ApplicationDbContext

[image]

Comment: looks like it's asking for a connection string.  This contains the information necessary to connect to the database (database name, password)

Comment: well I configured the connection string , I'm going to update the main post

Comment: Yes, you have updated the Connewction for the App, the Migration tooling looks for it differently.

Comment: So, the ususal question: which version (of EF)?

Comment: In which folder you are executing the script, and where is your DbContext class?

Comment: I'm going to update the information

Comment: As you are using Visual Studio - why don't you just run Add-Migration in the package manager console, while setting the startup project to the one containing your dbcontext class

Comment: you missed an s `options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:SportStoreProducts:ConnectionStrings"]))`

Comment: that ConnectionStrings did the trick. but hows that possible there is such a miss in the best book out there on ASP.NET by Adam Freeman?

Comment: the reason I'm not using Add-Migration is that I just started the EF,   I have no idea what options are available and this method was recommended by an author